# I have a threading.Event object, now python won't exit

Tags: python, python-multithreading

My code has a variable that is a threading.Event object.  Now, when I instantiate my program, or reference it in the Python prompt, I can't `ctrl+c` out of it.  What can I do to make my code exitable again?

Comment: Post a minimal example that exhibits the problem, but my guess is you need to make the thread a daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before exiting be sure to set the internal flag on the Event object:

```
  my_event_var.set()
```

Also you can intercept KeyboardInterrupt to set the flag on ctrl-c

```
   try:
       xx   
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       my_event_var.set()
       sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thanks -- maybe you could take a look at this one, as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761942/python-thread-event-doesnt-run-once-set